# Invalid operation for read only resultset: updateString

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc

Following is my code(Re-constructed) which select & update STATUS field depending upon the conditions. (Using Servlets, Oracle as Backend and JDBC driver)

```
ResultSet rs=null;
String query = "select A.NAME, A.ADDRESS, A.STATUS, B.CLASS from TABLE_ONE A, TABLE_TWO B where A.STATUS='N'";
pstmt = con.prepareStatement(query,ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
while(rs.next())
{
    String name = rs.getString("NAME");
    String address = rs.getString("ADDRESS");
    String class = rs.getString("CLASS");

    String msg = //Other statements to check what status to be set

    if(msg.equals("OK"))
        rs.updateString("STATUS", "S");
    else
        rs.updateString("STATUS", "E");
    rs.updateRow();
}
```

I am getting the error while updating:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Invalid operation for read only resultset: updateString
```

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

**Update 1:**
The same code was working when select statement was selecting data from single table, so is there any issue when selecting data from two tables in single query?

[**Note**: As @javaBeginner has mentioned in comments it will work only for one table.]

Comment: Try this:
     `rs.moveToInsertRow();
     rs.updateString("STATUS", "S");
     rs.insertRow();`
in place of just 
     `rs.updateString("STATUS", "S");`

I am not sure...Just check and let me know

Comment: @bhushan rs is `instanceOf` what. That might be readonly.

Comment: @RakeshJuyal I have declared rs as `ResultSet rs=null'

Comment: @Sandeep I am getting error when I try code in comment: `Invalid operation for read only resultset: moveToInsertRow`

Comment: @Bhushan can i know your exact requiremtn so that we can have alternate solution as per your requirement

Comment: @javaBeginner Above query is reconstructed to my similar requirement. My requirement is Read mails to be send from TABLE_ONE then read mail template & parameters from two different tables and when mail is sent then update the STATUS in TABLE_ONE to `S` (send). Let me know if you need more details.

Comment: @Bhushan which table is having column status

Comment: @javaBeginner TABLE_ONE is having column `STATUS`

Comment: @Bhushan do you have a primary key in table one?

Comment: @javaBeginner Yes. TABLE_ONE contains primary key.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37625/discussion-between-javabeginner-and-bhushan)

Comment: @Bhushan change your query to select * from table_one and let me know if it works or not

Comment: @javaBeginner If I select data from only one table (TABLE_ONE) then it works. but my requirement is to select data from three tables.

Comment: @Bhushan it will work only for one table,please have a look on jdbc api 2.2 section 5.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following limitations are placed on queries for enhanced result sets. Failure to follow these guidelines will result in the JDBC driver choosing an alternative result set type or concurrency type.

To produce an updatable result set (from specification):

- A query can select from only a single table and cannot contain any join operations.

In addition, for inserts to be feasible, the query must select all non-nullable columns and all columns that do not have a default value.
* A query cannot use "SELECT * ". (But see the workaround below.)
* A query must select table columns only. It cannot select derived columns or aggregates such as the SUM or MAX of a set of columns.

To produce a scroll-sensitive result set:

- A query cannot use "SELECT * ". (But see the workaround below.)
- A query can select from only a single table.

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```
 Statement stmt = conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);

//Execute a query
 String sql = "select A.NAME, A.ADDRESS, A.STATUS, B.CLASS from TABLE_ONE A, TABLE_TWO B where A.STATUS='N'";
 ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
//Extract data from result set
  rs.beforeFirst();
while(rs.next())
{
    String name = rs.getString("NAME");
    String address = rs.getString("ADDRESS");
    String class = rs.getString("CLASS");

    String msg = //Other statements to check what status to be set

    if(msg.equals("OK"))
        rs.updateString("STATUS", "S");
    else
        rs.updateString("STATUS", "E");
    rs.updateRow();
}
```

Just changed Prepared statement to create statement

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have tried you code, but even with `Statement` I am getting the same error.

Comment: @Sandeep How its going to workout if you change from preparestatement to statement.Even i would suggest not to use statement .prefered way is preparedstatement for increase of performance

Comment: @Bhushan It would help us if you could give the table schema and the code

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT *` makes the resultSet readonly. `SELECT COLUMN_NAME` makes it updatable.
So instead of `SELECT * FROM TABLE` use `SELECT COLUMN1, COLUMN2, ... FROM TABLE`.